# Tiny Core: startup script and persistence

Tags: startup, sysvinit, persistence, tinycore

I need a very lightweight, and I found Tiny Core Linux, which I installed following [this guide](http://wiki.tinycorelinux.net/wiki:install_hd), but I have several problems, related to adding SysVinit (in which is based) startup scripts:

1. Anything I write in /etc/init.d/ is lost after reboot
2. There are no /etc/rcX.d/ directories for the different runlevels. 
   I tried to avoid the 2nd problem calling my scripts at the end of the ones in /etc/init.d/, but because of the 1st problem, everything is lost when restarting.

After this, I checked the mounted devices, and the disk I selected to install, /dev/vda1, is mounted in /mnt/vda1, /home and /opt, and / corresponds to a rootfs:

```
rootfs on / type rootfs (rw,size=460176k,nr_inodes=163912)
```

Before these tests, I had tried other install ways instead of Frugal, like USB-HDD, but similar results, so, I think I am not understanding well how to work with this distro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found myself a solution for this.

Tiny Core Linux has a different [persistence style](http://wiki.tinycorelinux.net/wiki:start#persistence), the kernel and the root fs are always load from the default safe version, all the changes have to be applied in other way.

In this way, I found a script in /mnt/vda1/opt/bootlocal.sh that suggests adding other system startup commands there, so, I liked a copy of my script in /home/tc/. The original content of the file:

```
#!/bin/sh
# put other system startup commands here
```

So, I just added my script call below:

```
#!/bin/sh
# put other system startup commands here
sh /home/tc/script_name.sh
```

So, from there the right commands or script calls can be added. This scripts better should be saved in /home or in that same /mnt/vda/opt directories